# Dockerfile install package not working

Tags: 19.04, docker

I just started `docker-compose` after a while and am having issues I don't understand. I want to install `net-tools` on the container, but it does not seem to work like it used to.

my Dockerfile looks like this:
file1

```
FROM logstash:7.4.2
MAINTAINER xxx@gmail.com
# RUN  npm install -g bower && npm install --global gulp-cli

RUN uname -a
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y bash
# RUN apt-get update 
RUN apk add net-tools
```

file 2:

```
FROM elasticsearch:7.4.2
MAINTAINER xxx@gmail.com
# RUN  npm install -g bower && npm install --global gulp-cli

# RUN  apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
# RUN apk update
# RUN apk add --update net-tools
# RUN apk-install add 
RUN uname -a
EXPOSE 9200
```

docker-compose file looks like this:

version: '2'

```
services:
    logstash:
        build: ../images/logstash
        links: ["elasticsearch"]

    elasticsearch:
        build: ../images/elasticsearch
        ports:
            - "9200:9200"
```

When I run I get this:

```
Building elasticsearch
Step 1/4 : FROM elasticsearch:7.4.2
 ---> b1179d41a7b4
Step 2/4 : MAINTAINER xxx@gmail.com
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6a0133725b92
Step 3/4 : RUN uname -a
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 93c87715f6ab
Step 4/4 : EXPOSE 9200
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cd7479be90ef
Successfully built cd7479be90ef
Successfully tagged topology_elasticsearch:latest
Building logstash
Step 1/4 : FROM logstash:7.4.2
 ---> 642b82780655
Step 2/4 : MAINTAINER xxx@gmail.com
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bd9aa12c7c53
Step 3/4 : RUN uname -a
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6f4d7fdc0624
Step 4/4 : RUN apk add net-tools
 ---> Running in b3fdd2c42836
/bin/sh: apk: command not found
ERROR: Service 'logstash' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add net-tools' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I have tried `apt-get` but is not working.

How am I supposed to install packages on compose?

Comment: apt-get is used on Debian and Debian like Systems (as Ubuntu). apk is the equivalent command, but is used on Alpine Linux. On which Linux distro your Docker image is based on?